# _Document , AcceptAllRevisions() started Crashing once Msword 2013 installed

Tags: visual-c++, ms-word, com

I am using an application to convert the word files to XML format.
Application was running well till I had 2007 installed on my machine.
But once my machine upgraded to MS office 2013, application crashed at a line where `AcceptAllRevisions()` is called, throwing `KernelBase.dll` exception.

```
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
int nRetCode = 0;
// initialize MFC and print and error on failure
if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
{
    // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
    cerr << _T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed") << endl;
    nRetCode = 1;
}
else
{
  cout << "This is a SaveWordToXML ...! " << endl;

    // word_mask can be a full, relative, or no path but must have a file mask (wildcards ok)
    CString word_mask;

    // xml_mask can be a full, relative, or not specified but no filename should be given
    CString xml_path;

    bool got_word_mask = false;
    bool got_xml_path = false;

    got_word_mask = true;
    word_mask = "C:\\TestFolder\\*.doc";
    xml_path  = "C:\\TestFolder\\XML\\";

    if(got_word_mask)
    {
        CFileUtils fu_word_mask(word_mask);
        CFileUtils fu_xml_path(xml_path);

        // Go through each file that matches the input mask and save it to XML
        WIN32_FIND_DATA fd;
        HANDLE handle;
        if((handle = FindFirstFile(fu_word_mask.GetFullPath_File(),&fd)) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            do
            {
                CFileUtils fu_word_file(fu_word_mask.GetFullPath()+fd.cFileName);
                CFileUtils fu_xml_file(fu_xml_path.GetFullPath() + fd.cFileName);
                fu_xml_file.SetFileExt("XML");

                CWordDoc worddoc(fu_word_file.GetFullPath_File(),true,false);
                cout << " Word Doc created Successfully..! "<< endl;

                if(worddoc.IsOpen())
                {
                    cout << " Word Doc opened Successfully..! "<< endl;

                    worddoc.AcceptChanges();   // ***** Application crashes here  *******
                    cout << " Word Doc AcceptChanges Successfully..! "<< endl;
                                        worddoc.SaveAs(fu_xml_file.GetFullPath_File(),WORD_FILE_FORMAT_XML); // ***** Application crashes here  *******
                    cout << " Word Doc SaveAs Successfully..! "<< endl;
                }
                else
                    cout << "*** Error opening " << fu_word_file.GetFullPath_File() << endl;
            }
            while(FindNextFile(handle,&fd));
            FindClose(handle);
        }
    }
    else
        Usage();
}
return nRetCode;
}
// Defination of AcceptChanges 
bool CWordDoc::AcceptChanges()
{
    // If change tracking is currently on, accept all changes
    wordDoc.AcceptAllRevisions();
    return true;
}

int CWordDoc::SaveAs(CString filename, short file_format)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
    CString new_filename;
    if(filename.GetLength() == 0)
   {
      new_filename = filename;
   }
   // COleVariant var_filename((_bstr_t) filename);
   COleVariant var_filename(filename);
   COleVariant var_fileformat(file_format);

#if MSWORD8 // Word 97
   wordDoc.SaveAs(&var_bstr,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing); 
#elif MSWORD11 // Word 2003
wordDoc.SaveAs2(&var_filename,
                &var_fileformat,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing,
                    &vtMissing
            ); 
#else
#pragma message("Unknown MSWord version (must define MSWORD8 or MSWORD11)")
#endif
   return 1;
}

Application throws exception upon calling AcceptChanges() and if i 
comment  the line AcceptChanges(),it further throws exception at saveAs2() 

******  Any clue to solve this issue is greatly appreciated.*****
```

Comment: You'd have to change how COM library for MS Word 2013 is imported, and how the methods should be used. This seems legacy code, written for 2003 and 2007. You need to find the relevant API changes for MS Word 2013

Comment: Do you have more details on the error you get?

Comment: Getting the below exception :
unhandled exception in .exe (KERNELBASE.DLL) 0XE06D7363:Microsoft C++ exception"

Comment: First thing I'd do is check if the call to `ActiveDocument.AcceptAllRevisions` crashes when you call it from the Immediate Window of Word's VBA editor. If so, you probably need to check / repair your installation of Word.

Comment: to explore more on the issue , when i tried to call other functions like  wordDoc.AcceptAllRevisionsShown()  , wordDoc.Convert() then also it throws the same exception.  hence  i am thinking that , it is an exception issue occuring on calling  other methods not just saveAs2 / AcceptChanges.

Comment: Do i need to add any dependent dll's to solve the this issue ..

Comment: Finally i could able to crash the issue.Some someone who is facing the same issue , can do the below settings.

Comment: The issue is with newly added options in word 2013 , do the below settings to avoid the issue 
Open any word document Application , 1) Click FILE -> Options -> under the General Tab , uncheck the option "Open Email attachmets and Other uneditable files in reading view"   
2)Click FILE -> Options ->Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> File Block Settings -> uncheck the "Word 2003 and plain ML documents"